# Implement a rate-limit relating to the healthy servers count using haproxy

Tags: haproxy, rate-limiting

I want to implement a rate-limit system using the sticky table of HAProxy. Consider that I have 100 servers, and a limit of 10 requests per server, the ACL would be

```
http-request track-sc0 int(1) table GlobalRequestsTracker
http-request deny deny_status 429 if { sc0_http_req_rate(GlobalRequestsTracker),div(100) gt 10 }
```

Now if I want to make this dynamic depending on the healthy servers count, I need to replace the hardcoded `100` per the `nbsrv` converter.

```
http-request track-sc0 int(1) table GlobalRequestsTracker
http-request deny deny_status 429 if { sc0_http_req_rate(GlobalRequestsTracker),div(nbsrv(MyBackend)) gt 10 }
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
error detected while parsing an 'http-request deny' condition : invalid args in converter 'div' : expects an integer or a variable name in ACL expression 'sc0_http_req_rate(GlobalRequestsTracker),div(nbsrv(MyBackend))'.
```

Is there a way to use `nbsrv` as a variable inside the `div` operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*HAProxy* does no allow for nested function calls as far as I know. But you could store the number of backend servers in a variable and use it in the division (see `http-request set-var` in the *HAProxy* documentation). I have not tested it or used personaly, but I guess it could look like:

```
frontend <fe>
    http-request track-sc0 int(1) table <tbl>
    http-request set-var(req.<var>) nbsrv(<be>)
    http-request deny deny_status <code> if { sc0_http_req_rate(<tbl>),div(req.<var>) gt <val> }
```

See the *HAProxy* [documentation](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.9/configuration.html#4.2-http-request%20set-var).